# Running a statistical test to determine whether A (categorical) affects B (counts)

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, poisson-regression

I have data that consists of multiple variables. One of those variables, let's call it A, is categorical. The rest of the variables (i.e., B1, B2, ..., B12) are count data. I want to determine whether A affects any one of the count variables. To do this, I implemented the following procedure in R,

```
for (i in colnames(CountDataVariableNames){
    form <- formula(paste(i,'~','A'))
    print(form)
    model.p <- glm(form,data=df,family='poisson')
    print(Anova(model.p,type='II',test='LR'))
    }
```

I am following the code used in this source: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/J_01.html

I'm not sure what's going on here, but I get this kind of output:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: B1
    LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
A      1.27  1     0.2598
```

Does my procedure make sense? And what exactly am I doing? If the answer to the latter isn't easy, can anyone recommend any resources on statistical tests (preferably in `R`)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chunk

> ```
> for (i in colnames(CountDataVariableNames){
>     form <- formula(paste(i,'~','A'))
>     print(form)
>     model.p <- glm(form,data=df,family='poisson')
>     print(Anova(model.p,type='II',test='LR'))
>     }
> ```

performs a Poisson regression using $B[i]$ as response and the categorical variable `A` as a covariate, for every $i = 1,\ldots,12$. This regression model is useful in order to estimate the population means of the groups in `A`.

The chunk

> print(Anova(model.p,type='II',test='LR'))

runs a likelihood ratio test for the null hypothesis that all groups of `A` have the same population mean against the alternative that at least two groups have different population means.

Thus, the code does exactly what you have in mind.

**Remark.** There is a multiple comparison problem here due to the fact that you are running several tests (by means of the command `Anova`). Indeed, the joint confidence level may be far from, i.e. much lower than, what you have in mind. Therefore, consider adjusting your `Anova`'s p-values by means of a suitable multiplicity correction method. For this, check the `p.adjust` function of `R`.

Comment: This is so helpful! Also, thank you for recommending p.adjust!